# Google sheets - summarize matrix values

Tags: google-sheets

I have data like below:

```
1 2 3  A B C
4 5 6  A B C
7      C
3 4    B C
8 9    C B
1 2 3  C A B
```

The values 1-9 are assigned to values A, B, C - so for instance in first row A=1, B=2, C=3 etc.

I need to summarize all the elements above to get A, B, C.

How to start with this problem?

Final results:

```
A 7
B 22
C 29
```

Edit:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kzOtV9_SE5s7DaA_6YcZq6z08FpfXaIAjukyISew49U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you share a spreadsheet? it's difficult to understand the layout of your data!

Comment: Of course, I have added the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do your summary provided the ranges are the same dimensions.

```
=QUERY({FLATTEN(Arkusz1!F2:H)\FLATTEN(Arkusz1!B2:D)};"select Col1,SUM(Col2) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 order by SUM(Col2) desc label Col1'Summary'")
```

It is installed in a new tab called MK_Help